# help in Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, map, list

I have requirement to update user record based on insert/update Junction object between custom object and user. I need to update user custom field accountdef with junction object values(more than one for given user).I am newbie to Apex coding and having trouble with bulkifying the code. I have started something like this but could not navigate list to update user record.Any help will be appreciated.

```
trigger UpdateUserGUL on GUL_Account_to_User_Junction__c (after insert) {


    set<id> UserList    = new Set<id>();

    for (GUL_Account_to_User_Junction__c junc : Trigger.New){

       //add set of Ids
        userList.add(junc.UserId__c);

    }
   //query junction records based on userid set

GUL_Account_to_User_Junction__c[] juncrecords = [select id,UserId__c,GUL_Account_Name__c,Chatter_Group_Name__c 
                                                     from GUL_Account_to_User_Junction__c where UserId__c IN :UserList];
     Map<id, String> AccountsMap = new Map<id, String>();
     Map<id, String> ChatterMap = new Map<id, String>();


    //Create Map of records 
    for (GUL_Account_to_User_Junction__c j : juncrecords) {
    AccountsMap.put(j.UserId__c, j.GUL_Account_Name__c);
        ChatterMap.put(j.UserId__c, j.Chatter_Group_Name__c);

  }
```

Comment: @DougB Junction object records are more than one for given user with different account names. I need to male long string of accountnames like accountA,accountB,accountC.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** per Adrian's comment you technically don't need to query the User record.  You can use the User Id from the junction object alone to update the records.

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>();

for(GUL_Account_to_User_Junction__c junction : Trigger.new) {
    User userRecord = new User();
    userRecord.Id = junction.UserId__c;
    userRecord.Field_To_Update__c = ???;
    userList.add(userRecord);
}
update userList;
```

---

**Original Answer**

If you need to update the User object then you need to query the User records.

```
Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, Field_To_Update__c FROM User WHERE Id IN :userList];
```

Then loop through your junction object and update the User records per your requirements.

```
for(GUL_Account_to_User_Junction__c junction : Trigger.new) {
    User userRecord = userMap.get(junction.UserId__c);
    userRecord.Field_To_Update__c = ???;
}
update userMap.values();
```

Comment: Actually, if you have the `Id` already, you *don't* need to query. `update new User(Id=userId, Field_To_Update__c='Some Value'`.

Comment: Also note that it is demonstrably faster to put all field/value pairs in the `SObject` constructor if you know them at time of instantiation. :P

Comment: @AdrianLarson I did not know that it was faster via the constructor.  Learn something new everyday :D

Comment: @sfdcfox showed it somewhere on here. Can't seem to find it now, but I'll link to it if I do.